# How to add #from and #to in MySql DATETIME query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datetimepicker

I would like to know how to write a SQL query to select #from and #to any DATETIME. I know how to SELECT *FROM table but struggle to know how to SELECT from and to any dates so then a user would be able to select using a datepicker, this is code from my PHP also jQuery for the datepicker. Or any other ideas to connect to datepicker to DATETIME?

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE (time) BETWEEN ('2015-12-18 18:06:40') AND (NOW())";
```

jQuery

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyT00:00:00'});

$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyT23:59:59'});


  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="text" name="from" id="from"/>
  <label for="to">To:</label>
  <input type="text" name="to" id="to"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after selecting dates on frontend using jquery you need to pass those dates to server via GET or POST methods, then it will be possible to build a query you need

```
<form action="somefile.php" method="POST">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" name="from" id="from"/>
<label for="to">To:</label>
<input type="text" name="to" id="to"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

somefile.php code:

```
<?php
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE (time) BETWEEN ('$from') AND ('$to')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["name of column in register table you want to display"];
    echo $row["time"];
}
?>
```

Do not forget to escape incoming variables or you'll have security bug.

Comment: OK good idea, but how to write this ? Do you maybe have example ?

Comment: @JohnBoy do you have a form where those dates are set?

Comment: Yes, Iv added to picture above, is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I don't have a from and to in database, just time?

Comment: And do you know how to pass to server? I can do a post but how does the selected dates from jquery get to the $POST or GET?

Comment: when you submit a form it POSTs form input data to the php file you have specified in action attribute

Comment: So the selected jquery from a datepicker asks time in datebase the #from and #to ?

Comment: Jquery does not interact with database directly. First you should path from and to from browser to webserver. Webserver will receive from and to and path them to database so that you can filter your data between these two dates. After you get result from databes you should generate response in php and answer to browser which will show the results. So there are several steps you should go throw to solve your problem.

Comment: In my example there is only half of the task shown. When you path information from browser to webserver and feom webserver to database but not the response part

Comment: Would the response include this :                                                            var from = parseDateTime($('#from').val());                                             var to = parseDateTime($('#to').val());

Comment: '&from='+from+'&to='+to+'&rand='+Math.random

Comment: I'll get to my computer in several minutes and update my answer.. I am answering from phone.. Its hard to write code from here :)

Comment: Look Im sorry to trouble you but im still getting Error, I wonder if you might still beable to haelp a little when you have time?                                    syntax error, unexpected '$from' (T_VARIABLE) in